# Capybara Selenium with Javascript fetch fails with unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

**Setup**

Rspec with capybara and remote selenium (standalone-chrome-debug docker image) driver. Using StimulusJS as Javascript framework.

**Problem**

With the regular browser everything works like its supposed to. When i'm trying to test **javascript fetch** events with capybara selenium - the POST request fails with **unauthorized**. It feels like it is another browser session. Regular login forms for example work as well - it's just the javascript 'ajax' calls which don't.

**Capybara config**

```
Capybara.app_host = "http://#{ENV['TEST_APP_HOST']}:#{ENV['TEST_PORT']}"
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium

args = ['--no-default-browser-check', '--start-maximized']
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => args})
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :remote,
    url: "http://#{ENV['SELENIUM_HOST']}:#{ENV['SELENIUM_PORT']}/wd/hub",
    desired_capabilities: caps
  )
end
```

**HTML Snippet**

```
<a data-action="click->checkout-special-category#toggle" id="checkout-special-category-0" href="/dashboard/websites/db9cfdc39a7e251859f525b911466fd7/toggle_special_category?c=special-category-0">Click</a>
```

**Test Snippet**

```
first('#checkout-special-category-0').click
expect(first('#checkout-special-category-0')).to have_selector('.checkout-special-categories--is-active')
```

**Log**

```
Started POST "/dashboard/websites/db9cfdc39a7e251859f525b911466fd7/toggle_special_category?c=database-research" for 172.21.0.3 at 2019-06-19 15:14:53 +0000
Processing by Dashboard::WebsitesController#toggle_special_category as */*
  Parameters: {"c"=>"database-research", "id"=>"db9cfdc39a7e251859f525b911466fd7", "website"=>{}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is the domain name the fetch is being made to is not the same as the domain name the session cookies were set on - ie localhost vs 127.0.0.1, etc.

Comment: Then please edit your question to show a larger section of the test that shows how you're logging in, etc and also the JS code the click triggers.

Comment: @Oliver - OH -- you don't happen to be using an older version of Chrome do you? The default credentials init option to `fetch` changed a few versions ago.  One of the big differences between `fetch` and the XMLHttpRequest APIs is fetch used to not send any cookies by default.